# Enable CORS with Teapot in Smalltalk

Tags: cors, smalltalk

I am creating a REST API in smalltalk with Teapot http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~zeroflag/Teapot

But then I can not consume the data from my web application since CORS is disabled.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/components' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I can't find a way to make it work. I analyzed the code and the docs with no sucess.

Any idea?

Comment: Pls add an image or text with the error.... i think is due security of your browser but....

Comment: @Chevelle Please don't ask for images, we absolutely want all code and diagnostics in computer-readable form if at all possible.

Comment: The solution is : teapot after: '/*' -> [:req :resp | resp headers at: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' put: '*'];

Comment: Thanks @StephanEggermont

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is :

```
teapot after: '/*' -> [:req :resp | resp headers at: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' put: '*'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand [the mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) correctly, you'll probably want to be more specific than allowing `*`, especially in production. Most likely only your own domain